# Add existing table in database to entity, do not see .edmx file anywhere

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I right-clicked on my project, added a new Data item: ADO.NET Entity Data Model, named it and pointed it to my local database, selected all the tables and the wizard created several classes that represent these tables at the root level of my application.  I do not see any .edmx file so I can't right-click on the entity and say 'update from database' after creating a new table in the database.  Any ideas on how to fix this or should I have done this differently?

Comment: Have you select "EF Designer from database" when adding data model? EDMX file should be created on DB First approach where you can update model from DB later, if the project doesn't have any EDMX file but it includes data model classes seems that the project uses Code First.

Comment: Yes, I understand that the EDMX file should be there but even when I choose to view all files I do not see it anywhere.